# NullPointerException behavior on using Annotations

Tags: java, javafx, annotations, java-8, javafx-8

**EDIT** (Show the real problem instead of a sample code Annotation code)

I created my own way of loading `fxml` files in **Javafx 8** by using `Annotation` instead of using the `fx:controller` tag using this blog, [Designing JavaFX Business Applications](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/05/designing-javafx-business-applications-part-2/)

[image: Javafx fxml architecture]

I came up with this idea for dealing with **Javafx** `fxml` files.

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FXMLConfig {

    public String path();

}
```

So if I have a **Javafx** controller `SampleController`, it would look like this

```
@FXMLConfig(path = "/path/to/SampleController.fxml")
public class SampleController implements Initializable { ... }
```

To load the **GUI** I used a class named `JavafxWindow`

```
public class JavafxWindow {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private FXMLLoader loader;

    public void setup(Object controller) throws IOException {
        FXMLConfig config = controller.getClass().getAnnotation(FXMLConfig.class);
        this.loader = new FXMLLoader(controller.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(config.path()));
        this.loader.setController(controller);
        Parent parent = (Parent) loader.load();
        this.scene = new Scene(parent);
        this.stage = new Stage();
    }

    public void show() {
        this.stage.show();
    }

}
```

Now the `java.lang.NullPointerException` lies with in the lines

```
FXMLConfig config = controller.getClass().getAnnotation(FXMLConfig.class);
this.loader = new FXMLLoader(controller.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(config.path()));
```

I tested the code and it worked fine but `NPE` behavior occurs in the production which is a very annoying bug to users. `Exception` is thrown at `getAnnotation()` or `config.path()` at times of heavy usage. But the production code is deployed using `OSGi`, `Apache Felix 4.6.0` across **multiple** `bundles`. I am also using `Reflection` on other parts but no `NPE` is thrown.

Can you give me an implementation that comes with a level of checking to remove the abnormal `java.lang.NullPointerException` behavior?

- java version "1.8.0_45"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
- Apache Felix 4.6.0
- Ubuntu 14.04 / Windows 7 / Windows 8 / Windows 8.1

Thanks for the community's positive response.

Comment: have you managed to create a short program that throws a NPE on this line every time you run it? (in other words can you create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?) The only possible reason why this throws NPE should be when the class is not annotated...

Comment: `System.out.println(objectClass.getClass().getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class).toString);` -- The `toString` on the end isn't syntactically valid. Can you post real code that actually fails? It's hard to give advice when it appears you've edited your code for the post.

Comment: Sorry for that, I will edit my code as simple as possible

Comment: @Arjay I copied pasted your code and ran it: it printed `/path/to/metadata` as expected and I got no NPE. Can you show a complete example that throws a NPE? Without being able to reproduce your problem it is difficult to help you much because as far as I can see there is no problem! Maybe you just need to rebuild your project...

Comment: I have been writing/using custom annotation for sometime but I haven't seen any NPE of such...I quickly checked and I see that I always annotate my custom annotation interface with `@Inherited
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` - I am not sure if all four are always needed but at least I haven't seen any NPE, maybe that's the reason why?

Comment: I will edit the post to reflect the real implementation of my annotations as I may bring confusion among readers and **stackoverflow** enthusiasts in helping with my problem.

Comment: On which line is your NPE? The 1st or 2nd? If the 2nd it could be that `(controller.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(config.path())` returns null because the path is incorrect. You should split those two lines in smaller statements and log values to confirm which expression returns null.

Comment: The code is correct as it works as tested, only throws `NPE` on production or through random heavy usage. `NPE` is throws randomly on 1st and 2nd line.

Comment: How can the `setup` method of that JavaFX code experience “heavy usage”? How many user interfaces are you initializing simultaneously within a single JVM? By the way, there is no sign of how you control what gets passed into the `setup` method as it’s parameter is declared as an arbitrary `Object`. Of course, if somebody passes `null` into that method, you get the NPE on the first line, if someone passes an object of an arbitrary class not having that annotation, you’ll get the NPE on the next line. So you are most likely looking at the wrong place. Check the caller…

Comment: I mean when the whole system is used heavily, Is this a `JVM` issue and not on annotations specifically? or `classLoaders/reflections`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a a Minimal Complete Verifiable example. I haven't seen NPE of such type, so I'll post here the exact same way I always create my custom annotation for reference. Further questions welcome.

> Custom Annotation Class(interface)

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
@Inherited
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

@interface BasicBenefits {
    String bId() default "B-101";
    String bName() default "General Class A Employee";
}
```

> Class using the custom annotation(no need of any imports):

```
@BasicBenefits(bId="B-400", bName="General Plus Class A Employee")
public class Employee {
    String eId;
    String eName;
    public Employee(String eId, String eName){
        this.eId = eId;
        this.eName = eName;
    }

    public void getEmployeeDetails(){
        System.out.println("Employee ID: "+eId);
        System.out.println("Employee Name: "+eName);
    }
}
```

> Driver class to test out the above.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
public class TestCustomAnnotationBasicBenefits {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Employee emp = new Employee("E-100", "user3320018");
        emp.getEmployeeDetails();
        Class reflectedClass = emp.getClass();
        Annotation hopeBenefitAnn = reflectedClass.getAnnotation(BasicBenefits.class);
        BasicBenefits bBenefits = (BasicBenefits)hopeBenefitAnn;
        System.out.println("Benefit ID: "+bBenefits.bId());
        System.out.println("Benefit Name: "+bBenefits.bName());
    }
}
```